# How to get r'\\\|' from a yaml file

Tags: python, regex, yaml, pyyaml

I am using a yaml file to store some config data, including some (many) regex strings that I don't want to keep in code. Everything works except when I try to search for some incorrectly escaped pipe characters with `r'\\\|'`. I tried quoted, unquoted and literal strings in yaml, nothing works. Yaml and Python string escape rules together seem to conspire to keep the number of backslashes in a string even. I open and load the file with

```
f=open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf_8')
python_dict = yaml.load(f)
```

I'd like to reproduce

```
re.compile('\\\|')
```

using something like

```
re.compile(python_dict['escaped-pipes'])
```

Python 3.4 with PyYAML.

Comment: If you show us what you tried in your YAML file, we can better help you by pointing out what you did wrong.

Comment: Also, your text states that you want to produce `r'\\\|'`, but your code implies you want to have `'\\\|'`, which are two different things. I assume you want to reproduce `re.compile(r'\\\|')`.

Comment: Your answer solves my problem. Playing around, I also found another trick that works, though it's not as clean: `[\\][|]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In YAML, `\` is a special character only in doubly-quoted strings. The Python string `r'\\\|'` is a raw string, so it consists of three backslashes and a pipe. You have the following options to encode this in a YAML document:

```
plain:  \\\|      # plain scalar. YAML does not process the backslashes.
single: '\\\|'    # single quoted scalar. YAML also does not process the backslashes.
double: "\\\\\\|" # double quoted scalar. YAML does process escape sequences here, so you
                  # need to double the backslashes
```

Single-quoted scalars are kind-of the YAML equivalent of Python's raw strings.

You may have other characters in your regexes that may interfere with YAML's syntax. You may want to use block scalars instead, which treat *all* characters as content and are ended via indentation:

```
block: |-
  \\\|
next block: |-
  \\\|
```

`|` starts a *literal block scalar*, `-` causes the final linebreak (before the next item) to not be part of the scalar, which is what you want.